# puzzle on the range of differences of a set of numbers chosen between an interval

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, inequality

If I have picked a set of $n$ distinct integers where each element $x_k$ in the set is constrained by the interval $a < x < b$ and $a$ and $b$ are also given integers. What differences between pairs in the set are bound to occur? For example, if I pick 55 integers 0 and 101, the difference of one is bound to occur because $55 \cdot{2}>100$. However, the difference between pairs does not need to be larger than 55 because of the counterexample where all elements are spaced by 1. Likewise, the difference does not need to be 2 by way of many counterexamples. I'm led to believe that there does not need to be a difference of size 11, but there must be one of size 12.

Comment: I think 2 must occur as a difference for 55 integers in $[1,100]$. What is your counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=\{x\in\mathbb Z\mid a<x<b\}$ and let $N=|I|=b-a-1$. Let $q=\left\lfloor\frac{N}{2d}\right\rfloor$. Then $d$ must occur as a difference in all subsets of $I$ of size $n$ iff
$$
  n>qd+\min(d,N-2qd).
$$
Indeed consider the sets
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  X&=&\{a+2di+j\mid i,j\in\mathbb Z,\,1\leq j\leq d\},\\
  Y&=&X\cap I.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Then $|Y|=qd+\min(d,N-2qd)$. Note that no pair from $X$ has difference $d$. Indeed if
$$
  (a+2di'+j')-(a+2di+j)=d
$$
where $1\leq j,j'\leq d$ then $d|(j-j')$, so $j=j'$ giving $2(i'-i)=1$, a contradiction. The same must hold for $Y$. Thus for $n\leq|Y|$, any subset of $Y$ of size $n$ avoids the difference $d$.

Conversely suppose we choose a set $Z$ which avoids difference $d$. Note that
$$
  I\subseteq Y\sqcup(Y+d).
$$
Hence
$$
  Z=\bigsqcup_{y\in Y}Z\cap\{y,y+d\}.
$$
Since $Z$ avoids difference $d$, $|Z\cap\{y,y+d\}|\leq1$. Hence
$$
  |Z|=\sum_{y\in Y}|Z\cap\{y,y+d\}|\leq|Y|.
$$